# add results of nested dictionaries together

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a more efficient way to sum the keys of a subdictionary than the following?

```
for house in my_dictionary:
            artifact['Total']['Count'] += artifact['A']['Count']
            artifact['Total']['Action'] += artifact['B']['Action']
            artifact['Total']['Passive'] += artifact['C']['Passive']
```

I feel like there is a way to condense this, but I can't figure it out. I've written what is happening out in question form below. I came up with an answer, but I think that there is a better one out there.

If I have the following dictionary `my_dictionary`:

```
 {
        "A": {
            "Count": 3,
            "Action": 3,
            "Passive": 0
        },
        "B": {
            "Count": 1,
            "Action": 0,
            "Passive": 1
        },
        "C": {
            "Count": 1,
            "Action": 1,
            "Passive": 0
        },
        "Total": {
            "Count": 0,
            "Action": 0,
            "Passive": 0
        }
```

Once the `my_dictionary` has been created (with everything in `Total` blank), I to populate `Total` where `Total` is a sum of each of the other fields respective keys?

```
{
        "A": {
            "Count": 3,
            "Action": 3,
            "Passive": 0
        },
        "B": {
            "Count": 1,
            "Action": 0,
            "Passive": 1
        },
        "C": {
            "Count": 1,
            "Action": 1,
            "Passive": 0
        },
        "Total": {
            "Count": 5,
            "Action": 4,
            "Passive": 1
        }
```

Comment: Please show your attempts. Also, is set of keys fixed? Also, is there a reason why `Total` is a part of `my_dictionary` (it's more natural to just create new dictionary)?

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the values?

Comment: Updated, question. I have an answer that works. I want to know if there is a better (more arbitrary) answer that doesn't make me specify key names.

Answer (score 2):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) handles this pretty well with something like:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for o in my_dictionary.values():
   counts.update(o)

my_dictionary['Total'] = dict(counts)
```

Total will hold the result:

```
{'Count': 5, 'Action': 4, 'Passive': 1}
```

You don't need to define `Total` before this, `Counter` will make an entry in the `counts` dict for every key in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be rephrased as "how can I add together the values of keys in dictionaries, stored as dictionary values, assuming all those dictionaries have the same keys?"

That would look something like:

```
result = {k: 0 for k, _ in data[next(iter(data))].items()}
for _, d in data.items():
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k] += v
```

But perhaps not all of the dictionaries in the input have the same keys?

```
result = {}
for _, d in data.items():
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in result:
            result[k] += v
        else:
            result[k] = v
```

Next time, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.